# About pyqt5 manubar hotkey

Tags: python, pyqt5

I try myself to write a shortcut sample about the menubar, but I got some issue about it.
I have a `File(&F)` on the menubar, and in the `File(&F)` there is a **Save File (Ctrl + S)** item, I want to know that why I can't use the shortcut with `Ctrl + S` after I press `Alt + F`

```php
menuBar = self.menuBar()
fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu("&File")
self.fileMenu .addAction(self.SaveFileBt)
self.SaveFileBt.setShortcut("Ctrl+S")
```

Comment: Publish what value does `self.SaveFileBt` take?

Comment: Yes an MRE (wish I new the stackoverflow link for that) would be most helpful here as then we could see fully what you are doing and perhaps help you debug your situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example below, you have three ways to invoke the **`save` action**.

1. Press the corresponding menu items as shown in the image.
2. Use the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+S`
3. Use the keyboard shortcut `Alt+F+S`

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        menuBar    = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu   = menuBar.addMenu("&File")
        fileMenu.addAction("New")

        #         --->  & <---
        save = QAction("&Save", self)
        save.setShortcut("Ctrl+S")
        fileMenu.addAction(save)

        edit = fileMenu.addMenu("Edit")
        edit.addAction("copy")
        edit.addAction("paste")

        quit = QAction(QIcon("D:/_Qt/__Qt/img/exit.png"), "Quit",self)
        quit.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        quit.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)
        fileMenu.addAction(quit)

        fileMenu.triggered[QAction].connect(self.processtrigger)     

    def processtrigger(self, q):
        print( "{} is triggered".format(q.text()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.setWindowTitle("Qmenu")
    ex.resize(350,300)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: thanks friends you solve my problem ,but now i have a new question. Why press Alt+F+S is work , but Ctrl + S after press Alt + F is not working?

Comment: I thought this is the same action